# if integers and lists are objects in python why they have different treatments

Tags: python, list, object, integer

in the example below why the variable y doesn't change eventought, we change the value of x

```
x = 10
y = x
x = x + 1
```

I see the opposite here below

```
x = [0, 1]
y = x
x.pop()
```

in fact, everything in python is an object so why when we changed x, y changed automatically

Comment: Because integers are immutable and lists are mutable.

Comment: @Almester You might find the [explanation given here](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html) to be helpful